# Flutter json_serializable what if key can have different names

Tags: flutter, json-serializable

I am using json_serializable in Flutter to store a class in a file and read back from it. I am not posting the original class here for simplicity, but the principle is that half way through writing the app I decided that I wanted to change the variable name "aStupidName" to "name". How can I advise the code generation utility to assign the JSON value with the key "aStupidName", if it exists in the JSON, to the variable "name", but if the key "name" exists to assign this to the variable instead, i.e. in newer versions of the file?

Answer (score 8):

Hey what I think you can do is to provide multiple json key annotations to the same field in your model.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Person {

  @JsonKey(name: 'name') 
  @JsonKey(name:'first_name')
  final String firstName, lastName;

  final DateTime? dateOfBirth;

  Person({required this.firstName, required this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

alternatively you can give the json key annotation an explicit *fromJson* parameter a function to fully control how this field gets deserialized

Comment: Multiple JsonKey doesn't work for me.

Comment: Multiple JsonKey doesn't work for me neither

Answer (score 3):

here is what you can do:

```dart
factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  json['name'] ??= json['aStupidName'];
  
  return _$PersonFromJson(json);
}
```

basically, before the json conversion we're transferring the data of `aStupidName` to `name` key.

Comment: You have a syntax error. It should be " ??= "

Comment: it works both ways. '??=' is the formatted way but '?? =' works fine too

Comment: Interesting why it doesn't work for me. When I write them separately it detects it as a syntax error.

Comment: I've just tested this on dartpad, and looks like you're right. I apologize for commenting without testing, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use readValue property of @JsonKey

```
@JsonSerializabale()
class Something {
    static somethingOrSomethingElse(map, string) {
       return map['something'] ?? map['somethingElse'];
    }
    
    @JsonKey(readValue: somethingOrSomethingElse)
    late String value
}
```